# Найдите круг наибольшего радиуса, который можно полностью поместить в заданный выпуклый многоугольник

Tags: c++

Найдите круг наибольшего радиуса, который можно полностью поместить в заданный выпуклый многоугольник

Формат ввода
В первой строке записано число вершин в многоугольнике
N(3≤N≤10000). Следующие N строк содержат пары целых чисел xi and yi, не превосходящие по модулю 10^7 — координаты вершин выпуклого многоугольника в порядке обхода против часовой стрелке. Никакие три вершины не лежат на одной прямой.

Формат вывода
Выведите радиус искомого круга с точностью 4 знака после запятой.

```
4
0 0
1 0
1 1
0 1


0.500000000000
```

Вот мой код, он даёт неверный ответ на 6 тесте, помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <set>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

typedef long double ld;

const ld EPS = 1E-10;
const ld PI = 3.14;

struct pt {
    ld x, y;
    pt() { }
    pt(ld x, ld y) : x(x), y(y) { }
    pt operator- (const pt& p) const {
        return pt(x - p.x, y - p.y);
    }
};

istream& operator >>(istream& in, pt& p) {
    in >> p.x >> p.y;
    return in;
}

ld dist(const pt& a, const pt& b) {
    return sqrt((a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y));
}

ld get_ang(const pt& a, const pt& b) {
    ld ang = abs(atan2(a.y, a.x) - atan2(b.y, b.x));
    return min(ang, 2 * PI - ang);
}

struct line {
    ld a, b, c;
    line(const pt& p, const pt& q) {
        a = p.y - q.y;
        b = q.x - p.x;
        c = -a * p.x - b * p.y;
        ld z = sqrt(a * a + b * b);
        a /= z, b /= z, c /= z;
    }
};

ld det(ld a, ld b, ld c, ld d) {
    return a * d - b * c;
}

pt intersect(const line& n, const line& m) {
    ld zn = det(n.a, n.b, m.a, m.b);
    return pt(
        -det(n.c, n.b, m.c, m.b) / zn,
        -det(n.a, n.c, m.a, m.c) / zn
    );
}

bool parallel(const line& n, const line& m) {
    return abs(det(n.a, n.b, m.a, m.b)) < EPS;
}

ld get_h(const pt& p1, const pt& p2,
    const pt& l1, const pt& l2, const pt& r1, const pt& r2)
{
    pt q1 = intersect(line(p1, p2), line(l1, l2));
    pt q2 = intersect(line(p1, p2), line(r1, r2));
    ld l = dist(q1, q2);
    ld alpha = get_ang(l2 - l1, p2 - p1) / 2;
    ld beta = get_ang(r2 - r1, p1 - p2) / 2;
    return l * sin(alpha) * sin(beta) / sin(alpha + beta);
}

struct cmp {
    bool operator() (const pair<ld, int>& a, const pair<ld, int>& b) const {
        if (abs(a.first - b.first) > EPS)
            return a.first < b.first;
        return a.second < b.second;
    }
};

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<pt> p(n);
    for (pt& i : p) {
        cin >> i;
    }

    vector<int> next(n), prev(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        next[i] = (i + 1) % n;
        prev[i] = (i - 1 + n) % n;
    }

    set < pair<ld, int>, cmp > q;
    vector<ld> h(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        h[i] = get_h(
            p[i], p[next[i]],
            p[i], p[prev[i]],
            p[next[i]], p[next[next[i]]]
        );
        q.insert(make_pair(h[i], i));
    }

    ld last_time;
    while (q.size() > 2) {
        last_time = q.begin()->first;
        int i = q.begin()->second;
        q.erase(q.begin());

        next[prev[i]] = next[i];
        prev[next[i]] = prev[i];
        int nxt = next[i], nxt1 = (nxt + 1) % n,
            prv = prev[i], prv1 = (prv + 1) % n;
        if (parallel(line(p[nxt], p[nxt1]), line(p[prv], p[prv1])))
            break;

        q.erase(make_pair(h[nxt], nxt));
        q.erase(make_pair(h[prv], prv));

        h[nxt] = get_h(
            p[nxt], p[nxt1],
            p[prv1], p[prv],
            p[next[nxt]], p[(next[nxt] + 1) % n]
        );
        h[prv] = get_h(
            p[prv], p[prv1],
            p[(prev[prv] + 1) % n], p[prev[prv]],
            p[nxt], p[nxt1]
        );

        q.insert(make_pair(h[nxt], nxt));
        q.insert(make_pair(h[prv], prv));
    }

    cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << last_time << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

То есть нужно найти радиус вписанной окружности. Это площадь / полупериметр:

```cpp
ld radius(vector<pt> points) //радиус вписанной окружности
{
    ld sq = 0; //площадь многоугольника
    ld p = 0; // периметр
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
    {
        pt p1 = points[i];
        pt p2 = points[(i + 1 < points.size() ? i + 1 : 0)];
        sq += (p1.x + p2.x) * (p2.y - p1.y);
        p += dist(p1, p2);
    }
    sq = abs(sq) / 2;
    
    return sq / (p / 2); // площадь на полупериметр
}
```

Comment: Ваш код выдаёт WA на 3 тесте

Comment: Эта формула только для треугольника.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, [разве ?](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Кто-то обещал что вписанная окружность касается всех сторон многоугольника? Без этого требования формула применима только для треугольника.

Comment: Если не верите, примените формулу к прямоугольнику 1x1000.